# Android Gradle merge string resources

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I would like to create 2 different APKs (release and debug) using Gradle and I want to use different names for them ('appName' and 'appName debug').

I've found some solutions but it doesn't work for me:
[link 1](https://plus.google.com/118417777153109946393/posts/Dk65EACXqsh)
[link 2](https://plus.google.com/118417777153109946393/posts/EATUmhntaCQ)

I would like to install both apks on the device but I have the following error:

```
 Duplicate resources: 
 ...\src\release\res\values\config.xml:string/config_app_name,
 ...\src\main\res\values\config.xml:string/config_app_name
```

If I delete the `config_app_name` key from the `main\res\values\config.xml` then Gradle says the the key was not found.

I have 3 manifest files:

```
...\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml (this uses the `android:label="@string/config_app_name"`)

...\src\release\AndroidManifest.xml

...\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml

buildTypes {

    debug {
        packageNameSuffix ".debug"
        versionNameSuffix "-debug"
        buildConfig "public static final String PROVIDER_AUTHORITY = \"" + PROVIDER_DEBUG + "\";"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        buildConfig "public static final String PROVIDER_AUTHORITY = \"" + PROVIDER_RELEASE + "\";"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

sourceSets {
    debug {
        java.srcDirs = [
                'src/main/java']
        res.srcDirs = [
                'src/main/res',
                'src/debug/res']
    }

    release {
        java.srcDirs = [
                'src/main/java']
        res.srcDirs = [
                'src/main/res',
                'src/release/res']
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use one common key (strings, integers, dimens) in the main part of the project and override it in the release/debug part?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that it was only a naming issue. The name of the release package was misspelled. Sorry for this stupid problem.

Now the merge is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging

You defined multiple resources sources for build type. In such case they have same priority and can cause conflicts.

If you want correct merging you need to create separate main source set. It will have less priority than build types resources.

```
sourceSets {

    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/debug/res']

    }

    debug {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/debug/res']
    }

    release {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/release/res']
    }
}
```

But with such directory structure it must work out from the box without sourceSets definition.

Comment: I have a big project and I need the sourceSets declaration because some of the build types are using more than 2 srcDirs. But thank you for your explanation.